# Handle error for location.href that consumes node API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, frontend

Using angular js in the client side and node in the backend,
on click of a button, location.href is directed to my node API [which processes and generates a CSV file using node-csv, .csv file gets downloaded in client side].

location.href = "http://abc/example?ab=10&bc=10";

How to handle in client side, if the processing fails or node breaks in the middle of processing csv? How to check if its a successful or failure response on location.href?

Comment: There is no way on the clientside to detect it it errors if you are setting the current page's location to the CSV file. Shouldn't there be an error page that loads if there is an issue?

Comment: Can you let me know how can I do that? @epascarello

Comment: You can implement download another way, depending on supported browsers: create hidden iframe or just make ajax call.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov can you provide an example how to implement ajax call with location href

Comment: no location href - u just make ajax call and construct  base64 file url using Blob. (Wont work in IE9-)